# Position Div below absolute positioned image

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I'm creating a website for a friend. However I want to position a div containing 4 sections underneath an image absolute positioned. This has to be the case as I want it to resize with the change in window size without using any javascript. Can anyone think of a way to do this.

Heres the page:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24713212/0001_Adam_Plowdem_Videography/html/index.html

Basically I want the brightly coloured sections to start right after the image whatever the browser size.

Really appreciate any help, thanks,

Matt

```
<style>

body{
width: 99%;
height: 1050px;
background-color: #FFF;
font: 80%/1.65 "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

#header{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
position: fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color: #FFF;
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #EBE8E4 100%);
/* Mozilla Firefox */
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #EBE8E4 100%);
/* Opera */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #EBE8E4 100%);
/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #EBE8E4));
/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #EBE8E4 100%);
/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #EBE8E4 100%);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#nav{
width: 600px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right:0;
height: 50px;
margin-right: 20px;

}

#nav ul{
list-style: none;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
margin: 0;
display: block;
right:0 !important;
}

#nav li{
display: inline-block;
height: 50px;
border-bottom: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav li a{
display: block;
height: 50px;
padding-top: 16px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-bottom: 0px !important;
border-bottom: none;
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
/*text-transform: uppercase;*/
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav a:hover{
color: #000;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0;
-moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0;
transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0;
}

.banner {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
background: url(img/adam.jpg) center center;
background-size: cover;
position:absolute;
top:50;
left:0;
z-index:-2;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(200,200,200,0.9) 0 4px 10px -1px;
box-shadow: rgba(200,200,200,0.9) 0 4px 10px -1px;
/*position: relative;
margin-top: -60px;*/
}

.overlay {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
background: url(img/overlay.png) center center;
background-size: cover;
position:absolute;
top:50;
left:0;
z-index:-1;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
/*position: relative;
margin-top: -60px;*/
}


.about {
min-height: 170px;
padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px;
text-align: center;
background: red;
display: block;
}

.about2 {
min-height: 170px;
padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px;
text-align: center;
background: blue;
display: block;
}

.about3 {
min-height: 170px;
padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px;
text-align: center;
background: yellow;
display: block;
}

.about4 {
min-height: 170px;
padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px;
text-align: center;
background: green;
display: block;
}

#container{
background-color: red;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
width: 1000px;
height: 70%;
}


</style>

<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Start Navigation -->
<div id="header">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul></div>
</div>
<!-- End Navigation -->

<!-- Start Main Image -->

<section class="banner" style="height: 100%;">
</section>

<!-- End Main Image -->
<div style="width: 99%;
height: 100%;">
<section class="about">
  <h5>Hello World</h5>
</section>
<section class="about2">
  <h5>Hello World</h5>
</section>
<section class="about3">
  <h5>Hello World</h5>
</section>
<section class="about4">
  <h5>Hello World</h5>
</section>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Show some code or make a jsfiddle, so we can fiddle !

Comment: using position:absolute removes that item from the normal flow of the document. no other items will respond to the space that it creates. I'd recommend trying something other than position:absolute

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: @1ntello code added :)

Comment: @jbenjohnson is there not a work around? maybe use php to return the height of the browser and use that value as the top margin?

Comment: i don't understand why you are using position:absolute in the first place. what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @jbenjohnson its what worked when making the image resize depending on the browser window size so that it is full screen all the time. Making it anything else just didnt work!

Comment: @user2556141 You can try my answer. Its working for me.

Comment: is there going to be text over the image? if not, i would recommend making it and <img> instead of a background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do as make the div style to below that contains all the 'about' sections.

```
height: 100%;
margin-top: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
width: 99%;
```

This will make the div start exactly after where the image ends. This would resolve your issue.

Comment: just fyi - this technique places the content at the bottom of the browser, not at the bottom of your image. if you ever change the height of your <section.banner> then you'll need to adjust top:100% to whatever the new height is

Comment: I guess No. As image height is set to 100% of the browser, so the top: 100% would work. If you need to decrease the height, then you also need to set the same value to the top.

Comment: yep that's exactly what i said! :)